# data frames: apply on two columns based on values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, apply

say i have a simple dataframe, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'letters' : ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'numbers' :[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

the table looks like this 
[simple dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD52P.png)

now say i have a short list,  `to_remove = ['b','d']` 
how can i find the rows on my dataframe, where the value of 'letters' column is in 'to_remove' and modify this line BOTH in 'letters' and 'numbers' to None?  so im left with
a 1
None None
c 3
None None
e 5
 been looking for hours. thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check by list of values and set `None` by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
to_remove = ['b','d']

df.loc[df['letters'].isin(to_remove), ['letters','numbers']] = None
#all columns
#df.loc[df['letters'].isin(to_remove)] = None
print (df)
  letters  numbers
0       a      1.0
1    None      NaN
2       c      3.0
3    None      NaN
4       e      5.0
```

If want filtering rows use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by inverting boolena mask by `~`:

```
df1 = df.loc[~df['letters'].isin(to_remove)]
print (df1)
  letters  numbers
0       a        1
2       c        3
4       e        5
```

Answer (score 1):

Or can use `df.eval` for `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[df.eval('letters in @to_remove'),['letters','numbers']]=None
```

But since no you're just listing all the columns of dataframe to be assigned, why not just:

```
df.loc[df.eval('letters in @to_remove')]=None
```